# Getting Cross-thread operation not valid in MDIParent

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception, mdi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

I am trying to close the base of a form from another thread. I am getting the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MDIParent' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

for the below line:

```
MDIParent.MDIParentRef.BaseClose();
```

Comment: So far you've stated facts. They seem like perfectly reasonable and sensible facts. Did you have a *question*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform the operation on the UI Thread:

```
if (InvokeRequired) 
    Invoke(new Action(MDIParent.MDIParentRef.BaseClose));
else
    MDIParent.MDIParentRef.BaseClose();
```

Comment: @Mehrdad, i tried to use as above. am getting error : Cannot convert lambada expression to type "system.delegate" because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: @Mehrdad, if(InvokeRequired) always have the value as false. Because of that the else condition is executing and same error as above is coming again.

Comment: karthk: that's a little weird. If you're sure you're calling it from another thread, replace the whole thing with the `Invoke(...)` line.

Comment: @Mehrdad, the reason why i  am using BaseClose() is.. I am using shellLib and creating a custom desktop task bar. When i try to close the task bar using BaseClose(), it closes that perfectly. But the problem is the space occupied by taskbar is blocked and it is not released. what would be the problem. Advise me on this. Thanks.

Comment: karthik: That's a separate issue. I'm not sure what you should do. Post it as a separate question. Someone will answer.