# Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Okay, I know why this is giving me this error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread
>   other than the thread it was created
>   on.

But... How can I make this workable?

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(()=>
{
   // do really hard work and then...
   listView1.Items.Add(lots of items);
   lots more UI work
});
t.Start();
```

I don't care when, or how the Thread finishes, so I don't really care about anything fancy or over complicated atm, unless it'll make things much easier when working with the UI in a new Thread.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523878/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-in-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485786/error-cross-thread-operation-not-valid or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377529/cross-thread-operation-not-valid or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397370/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-in-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010602/c-cross-thread-operation-not-valid or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439065/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-in-c

Comment: +1 @blue, yeah there seems to be a whole class of similar questions regarding this all asked in a slightly different way but with the same core idea that UI operations must be performed on the same thread.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't.  UI operations must be performed on the owning thread.  Period.

What you *could* do, is create all those items on a child thread, then call `Control.Invoke` and do your databinding there.

Or use a `BackgroundWorker`

```
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (s, e) => { /* create items */ };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => { /* databind UI element*/ };

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Solid answer, but I'm curious about why "You can't" is true. Do you have any further reading?

Answer (score 15):

When you access the from's property from another thread, this exception is thrown.
To work around this problem there's at least 2 options.

1. Telling Control to don't throw these exceptions (which is not recommended):

   `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`
2. Using threadsafe functions:

   ```
   private void ThreadSafeFunction(int intVal, bool boolVal)
   {
       if (this.InvokeRequired)
       {
           this.Invoke(
               new MethodInvoker(
               delegate() { ThreadSafeFunction(intVal, boolVal); }));
       }
       else
       {
           //use intval and boolval
       }
   }
   ```