# textbox in new thread

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

My function I put to new thread, but it doesn't work. I have exception:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

My code:

```
    void licz()
    {
        int wynik = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {

            wynik =+ i;
            textBox1.Text += wynik.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

        }
        MessageBox.Show("Wynik: " + wynik);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Thread th1 = new Thread(licz);
         th1.Start();


    }
```

How fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access UI Elements from another thread than the one that created it (the UI thread). Your alternatives would be to use a callback, raise an event that your UI thread is subscribed to or use the [Dispatcher](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx&ei=8sVkT62CIoSWgweK5OXvAg&usg=AFQjCNEb054gUIMtIovcFwvUrDRS6bE-KQ&sig2=lZzVeykenGARyGm_JEe9Mw) if you're working with WPF or Silverlight.

If you give more details on what you're trying to achieve and the technology you're using I could give a more complete answer.