# Get Control in Focus when loading .exe

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading, focus

I have vb.net form that opens another vb.net exe to test.  I am trying to test if a specific textbox has focus when the exe is loaded.

My tester form loads the exe using Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(_path)
It then  runs the FormtoTest on a new thread

I use the System.Type.GetProperty() and GetFields() functions to get all of the FormtoTest's input fields and their properties.

I then find this textbox in the list of input fields,

But when I call the System.Type.GetProperty("Focused"), I get an error:
"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtID' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid) it may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you will need to use delegates

references

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx

This is in C# but explains the basic concepts as well.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2083/The-key-to-multi-threaded-Windows-Forms-UI-interac

Comment: Thanks between all the comments, I was able to figure it out.