# Getting Cross-thread Operation Not Valid from SerialPort.Read()

Tags: vb.net, exception, serial-port, arduino

I am writing a program in Visual Basic that will read text commands from the serial port that are sent using an external controller (an Arduino). However, when I try to test the code I get an error:

> Cross-thread Operation Not Valid

Here is what the code looks like:

```
 Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim Data As String = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
    If Data = "l" Then
        LeftRadio.Checked = True
    ElseIf Data = "r" Then
        RightRadio.Checked = True
    ElseIf Data = "c" Then
        CenterRadio.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles connect.Click
    If Not SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM3"
        SerialPort1.Open()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

Comment: The DataReceived event runs on a worker thread, you cannot update any controls directly.  Use the *hundreds* of previous questions about this exception to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5037487/41956) and [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Short answer: you perform UI operation in not-UI (main) thread what is not permitted.

In VB.NET should be something like:

```
Dim check = Sub()
                LeftRadio.Checked = True
            End Sub
LeftRadio.Invoke(check)
```

Comment: I read that but still do not fully understand how to implement into my code as that isnt visual basic. I am new to this , do you have insight on how I would go about doing it ?

Comment: @user1683391: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the `DataReceived` event doesn't usually work the way you think and can block the serial port while code runs in the event.

My preference is to add a `Timer` to the form that runs at a reasonable speed such as 5 times per second.

In the Timer `OnTick` event you can test `SerialPort1.BytesAvailable` to see if data has arrived. Then use `ReadExisting()` as you have above.

The timer code will be less prone to cross thread issues.