# Get information from a method in one class to mainform when it is invoked?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

This is a method in the other class that i want to get the message from in my mainform.

```
 string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
 Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Can i subscribe to this method from the main method somehow to get the data each time this method is triggered?

Edit: 
Okay so this is what my code looks like now:

```
                    } else {
                    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                    DoSomething(message);
                    //Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log("Error recieving data: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public delegate void SomethingHappenedHandler(string s);
    public SomethingHappenedHandler SomethingHappened = null;

    public void DoSomething(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        var sh = SomethingHappened;
        if (sh == null)
        {
            sh(message);
        }
    }
```

And in the main method:

```
            dht.dhtNode.SomethingHappened += (msg) =>
        {
            talkText.Text += "[Friend]:  " + msg + "\n\n";
        };
```

But it does not trigger it? what else should i do to make it work?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. What's this other method? Why can't you just call it? What went wrong when you tried to call it?

Comment: the method is running in another thread and is triggered when i get an udp packet so i cant call it as it is.

Comment: Methods are not "in threads". What did you try to do to call it, and what was the problem when you did?

Comment: Now the context has changed. It is now a followup question because `Okay so this is what my code looks like now` is my answer's copy (which also explains your *new* problem)

Comment: Try `if (sh != null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a delegate and subscribe to it. For ex,

```
someInstance.SomethingHappened += (msg) =>
    {
        //your code
    };
```

---

```
public delegate void SomethingHappenedHandler(string s);
public SomethingHappenedHandler SomethingHappened = null;

public void DoSomething()
{
    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    Console.WriteLine(message);

    var sh = SomethingHappened;
    if (sh != null) sh(message);
}
```

**EDIT:**
And to display the result in a UI control you should be aware of Cross-threads operations. [Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid)