# Instantiating User Control in a Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, task-parallel-library

In my application, I have a new Windows Form (called Monitor) which consists of basically a big display (which is a custom user control), which itself consists of many small charts (also user controls) arranged in a grid.  When I instantiate the monitor form, a new display object is created, which then goes on to create a bunch of chart controls.  The chart controls are then added to "display's" controls collection (`Controls.Add(chart)`), which completes the loading of display, and then display is added to "monitor's" control collection, and the form is shown.

The problem I have is that each chart control takes about 0.5s to load, and we can have around 75 of them in one display object.  Therefore, I would like to create these charts in parallel, to speed up the load time.  I took advantage of the TPL method `Parallel.ForEach` to accomplish this.

My code looks like this, inside the "display" object's constructor:

```
public class DisplayControl : UserControl
{
    public DisplayControl()
    {
        var chartNames = new string[] { "chart1", "chart2", ... };
        var builtCharts = new ConcurrentBag<Chart>();

        // Create the chart objects in parallel
        Parallel.ForEach(chartNames, name =>
            {
                // The chart constructor creates the chart itself, which is a 
                // custom user control object (inherits UserControl), composed  
                // of other various WinForm controls like labels, buttons, etc.
                var chart = new Chart();
                chart.Name = name;
                builtCharts.Add(chart);
            }
        );

        // Clean up the charts and add them to "display's" control collection
        foreach(var chart in builtCharts)
        {
            // Do some unimportant modifications to the chart, synchronously
            ...

            this.Controls.Add(chart);
        }
    }
}
```

The DisplayControl constructor is called on the main thread by the main form, Monitor, and the DisplayControl instance itself is added to Monitor's ControlCollection.  Monitor is then shown using `Monitor.Show()`, which is just the `Show` method of a `Form` class.

The main issue I am experiencing is that the DisplayControl constructor throws an `InvalidOperationException` occasionally at the `this.Controls.Add` line, citing the following:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'panel' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

I should note that `panel` is just a panel WinForms control, which is created in the `Chart()` constructor.

Finally, the code appears to work just fine about 90% of the time, and these errors are seemingly random.  If I get the error, I can usually just re-run the code immediately and it will work.

My goal is to eliminate this error and make this all thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All operations regarding `System.Windows.Forms` must be executed in the main thread. There are numerous questions about this; like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid). So if you're just creating the charts in your parallel loop, then better keep it as a plain `foreach`.

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that the charts take on the order of 0.5 seconds to even return from the constructor, and when you have ~75 of these, there's about a 40 second load time.

Comment: @ccampo: Maybe you can do whatever the constructor is doing asynchronously.

Comment: There's not much you can do afaik. You could try to optimize the code of the `Chart` class, or maybe cache the form, instead of closing and disposing it.

Comment: @MichaelLiu is right. Classes and methods that don't belong to the forms namespace, can be executed asynchronously.

Comment: @MichaelLiu @Matthias I really wish I could, but all that `Chart()` constructor is doing is... creating more WinForm controls!

Comment: Is it a library or your own implementation?

Comment: Inside the `Chart()` constructor, it is basically creating a bunch of third party charting controls, as well as some other things like labels, etc.. The `Chart` control itself is our own implementation, but it is just a collection of WinForm and 3rd party WinForm controls

Comment: Depending on how much controls are involved, it might be better to paint the control yourself.